# Reading many text files into array of string c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm trying the following code to read a number of text files into array of string

```
for (int j = 0; j < paths.Length; j++)
{
   StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(paths[j]);

   string file_text = fs.ReadToEnd();
   textToarray[j] = file_text;

   fs.Close();
}
```

Can I do the same procedure with one time employing of the `StreamRreader`? is there any better way?

Comment: Only purist points like explicit filestream and a using clause. After that it's whether you should be doing this.

Comment: If you use a StreamReader you should use it in a USING block or inside a TRY FINALLY block to make sure it is disposed correctly. As the others say File.ReadAllText() seems like a good alternative in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ and [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) methods together to do it in a single line of code:

```
var textToArray = paths.Select(p => File.ReadAllText(p)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you dasblinkenlight :)